# Change xenbr0 bridge name in XenServer

Tags: xenserver

I want to setup a bridge  in XenServer with a name other than xenbr0 , for example cloud0.

I edited those files and their contenent so they can handle a bridged connection:

- /etc/xensource-inventory

> CURRENT_INTERFACES='cloud0'
>
> MANAGEMENT_INTERFACE='cloud0'

- /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-xenbr0 to ifcfg-cloud0

> DEVICE="cloud0"

- /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

> BRIDGE=cloud0

but it didn't gave a result even with "ifdown xenbr0" and all those modifaction are not persistent with XenServer reboot.

So what are the right steps to change the xenbr0 bridge name ?

Thx

Comment: No sure why you want to do this. In general, don't choose XenServer if you wan't to hack - choose the Xen kernel.

Comment: So there is no way to make those changes in xenserver because files are autogenerated ?